# Is a comma correct here?

Tags: punctuation

In the following sentence:

> He was the first of his kind, the first king.

Is a comma correct here? Does it make sense, it sounds a little off to me.

I'd rather not add any new words to the sentence, so I want to avoid the following:

> He was the first of his kind, he was the first king.

– even though that's exactly what I want the first sentence to mean.

Comment: The second sentence is a comma splice and definitely not generally accepted. The first is okay to me, but you can change the comma for a colon or a dash if you want (that goes for the second version, too: it would be fine with a colon/dash instead of a comma).

Comment: he was the first king

Comment: @JonMarkPerry What?

Comment: @Daft I think JonMarkPerry is asserting that the OP's sentence is a tautology

Comment: @MarvMills Thanks for explaining it. Jon Mark Perry obviously didn't feel the need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The first king" in your sentence is an **appositive**, a noun phrase that further identifies a noun. If an appositive comes at the end of a sentence, as in your example, it needs a comma before it:

> He was the first of his kind, **the first king**.

If an appositive is at the beginning of a sentence, it needs a comma after it:

> **A Pulitzer-winning novel**, *For Whom the Bell Tolls* is of course taught in many schools.

If an appositive is in the middle of a sentence, it needs a comma before and after it:

> My cousin, **a professional golfer**, is always sunburned.

Comment: Cheers Nicole, much appreciated.